# DUB: How to specify version of git repo?

Tags: d, dub

I use DUB, and want to include ncurses to project https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/ncurses/

it have not explicitly version specification on github page. But during build DUB ask me to specify version explicitly:

`WARNING: A deprecated branch based version specification is used for the dependency ncurses. Please use numbered versions instead.`

How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.dlang.org/package-format

Looks like your "DUB" tool is a later version than the tool used to create the 'package.json' file in the GIT repo. The message is rather obscure, but it's not a GIT message. It seems to mean that the 'ncurses' repo needs updating; send them a pull when you work out how.

Answer (score 3):

This is dub complaining because the entry in your dub.json (or package.json) is "ncurses": "~master"

However, dub is trying to move away from using the "~master" branch (as it's prone to constant changes in most projects)

As the only available branch tag on ncurses is ~master you'll have to use it. I'm suprised that dub isn't working with the master branch however, as it's only a WARNING message, not ERROR.

Maybe pinging the owner of ncurses to create a tag may be a good idea?